# Missing tools.jar (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, openjdk, jdk

The command

```
$ ~/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

says

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

I have searched for the solution to this error, and as far as I can tell, I've done everything right to correct this error. But it still persists.

1. `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` (CHECK)
2. `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` (CHECK)
3. `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

   ```
   * 0    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071   auto mode
   ```
4. `find /usr/lib/jvm | grep tools.jar`

   - finds nothing. (FAIL)

What am I missing?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474963/android-studio-tools-jar-file-is-not-present-in-classpath). Also make sure you set `JAVA_HOME` in the [correct](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Other_files) config file.

Answer (score 6):

As per output mentioned for command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I can see that you have only JRE installed but you also need JDK to compile and run the code.

You can install JDK for Java 8 using following command :

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And then run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

command and select JDK instead of JRE.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error, and found that I did not have the java compiler installed.

Try `javac -version` and see if you have it installed. If not,

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and hopefully that will fix your problem.

**EDIT:** I see now after rereading that you have already installed the jvm once, but I had it installed as well, so I'm not sure if something got updated or what but like I said it worked for me.

Comment: You saved my day.  I had installed JRE, but not JDK.  Used above command to install JDK and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. There has nothing to do on JAVA_HOME or configure-alternatives. The truth is there is no tools.jar in oracle-java-9(even in open-jdk). To use android-studio in the Ubuntu you must use java-8. Why? I don't know and I don't care! I must to learn Android Studio, so whatever...

Install jdk-8 for android-studio, change PATH and JAVA_HOME environment and be happy!

Works for me...

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

Answer (score 1):

because `studio.sh` is a script itself, running `JAVA_HOME=..` is not enough. Instead, make sure you run:

> `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a Oracle JDK installed and conflicted with OpenJDK, use:

> export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score -1):

IN LINUX DEBIAN :

1.- Open Synaptic and search "openjdk".

2.- checks that do not have more than one installed version of the package "openjdk-?".

3.- uninstall all file with old version and left alone all file with new version.

4.- Check that your Java Version have change from terminal "#java -version".

5.- try again install  studio.sh